# No data in DE from query

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, dataextensions

I have a query with the following query text

```
SELECT 
s.SubscriberKey
,s.EmailAddress as Email
,j.EmailName
,s.EmailAddress from  _Job j 
INNER JOIN _Sent se on j.JobID = se.JobID
INNER JOIN _Subscribers s ON se.SubscriberKey = s.SubscriberKey
WHERE se.EventDate < GetDate()
```

When I run start the query and check my target DE, there is no data within the DE. Do I need to specify which subscriber the query needs to look at or other? Im not sure if I missed a step

Answer (score 0):

The Query looks good to me, so for troubleshooting i would try the following steps
1.Run the query in an automation rather than running it from interactions tab, notification helps to check if it completed successfully.
2. If the query failed: Checking if target DE has subscriberkey field as primary key? or if any of the fields are set to non-nullable ? that may cause the query to fail as the result may have duplicates/null values based on sent data.
3. If step 1 and 2 are Passed, i would try running query with only 1st join condition and check if we are getting results, then add 2nd join condition and repeat same till Where clause checking one condition at a time.. this step is to check which condition might be scrubbing off the data.

Hope this works!

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
SELECT 
s.SubscriberKey,
s.EmailAddress as Email,
j.EmailName,
s.EmailAddress from  _Job j 
INNER JOIN _Sent se on j.JobID = se.JobID
INNER JOIN _Subscribers s ON se.SubscriberKey = s.SubscriberKey
WHERE DATEADD(DD, DATEDIFF(DY, 0, se.Eventdate), 0) >= DATEADD(DD, DATEDIFF(DY, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
```

If you're running in parent BU so use ENT in all DataView table.